Tkinter With Images
With the following code, I can not display an image in a tkinter cell:
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.geometry=("1000x1000")

def orig():
    orig_image = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Image file", "*.jpg"), ("All files", "*.")])
    my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(orig_image))
    lbl = Label(image=my_img)
    lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)


orig()

root.mainloop()

But, by taking this out of the method, it works fine:
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.geometry=("1000x1000")

orig_image = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Image file", "*.jpg"), ("All files", "*.")])
my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(orig_image))
lbl = Label(image=my_img)
lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)

root.mainloop()

What am I missing ?
This is part of a larger project where I want to display an "original" OCR scan image and then with other methods, display a "corrected image" next to the original image (in another column) to show if that correction was an improvement or not.

there are some issues of your code

Unfortunately, the geometry method is being assigned incorrectly. It should be invoked instead of assigned.

To the first code block, you made a definition of a function orig() but let it remain unevaluated.

The PhotoImage object needs to be held on to as an attribute to prevent it from being lost to garbage collection.


try this way:
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("1000x1000")  # Corrected: called as a method

def orig():
    global my_img  # Important: keep a reference to prevent garbage collection
    orig_image = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Image file", "*.jpg"), ("All files", "*.*")])
    img = Image.open(orig_image)
    my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    lbl = Label(root, image=my_img)
    lbl.grid(row=0, column=0)

orig()  # Call the function to open file dialog and display image
root.mainloop()


You don't need Global. It is not a practical.

Thank you.  That got me back on track.  The geometry mistake was a fast cut & paste with a correction from my actual code.  I was actually setting the window to max width & height but didn't want to include all of the extra fluff.


I can not display an image in a tkinter cell.

You need reference image.
Add this on line 12, lbl.image= my_img
Edit:
Screenshot:

